# How to print a 64 bit number in NASM?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I'm writing a subroutine that's supposed to print the decimal value of whatever gets passed to it in rdi. It works great for every number that can be represented with 32 bits. As soon as 64 bit values get involved things break down.

if I pass 4294967295 or 0000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111b as an argument it prints as expected. But if I do

```
mov rdi, 4294967295
inc rdi
call Print_Unsinged
```

I get the wrong result (X96 to be exact).

I'm checking the size of the argument this way:

```
mov rbx, rax ; rax has the orginal arg at this point
xor ebx, eax
cmp rbx, 0
jne isQword

mov ebx, eax
xor bx, ax
cmp ebx, 0
jne isDword

cmp ah, 0
jne isWord

jmp isByte
```

What ends up happening is that a value that should have bits beyond ebx set and should be jumping to isQword jumps to isDword instead. So the first character printed ends up being garbage while the rest of the number prints fine. Look at the first code snippet: I would expect the argument value to be 0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000b, and then that would trigger a jump to isQword because rbx would have a bit set after ebx was cleared. But no, this value filters all the way down to isByte and prints "X96".

I can't figure this out, can anyone help?

Comment: 32 bit operations zero the top 32 bits automatically so your test fails. `shr rbx, 32; jnz isQword` is an alternative.

Comment: Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: This has the potential to be a good question. Its refreshing for the Linux tag. You need to show the code you are using to print the 64-bit register; not the snippet used to check the size. There also seems to be a disconnect in the code you provided. You show the value in `rdi`, but then you start operating on a value in `rax`. `rbx` should probably be preserved because its used for the Global Offset Table (GOT) in a lot of code.

Comment: The question pertains to detecting the size, the rest of the code is irrelevant as of now. The printout is wrong because it goes into the 32 bit case for 64 bit value. As for preserving `rbx`, it may very well be preserved since we don't see the full code. Also, if you don't interoperate with other code you don't need to follow the ABI.

Comment: @jww: `rbx` is call-preserved in the x86-64 SysV ABI, but it's not used for the GOT.  64-bit code uses RIP-relative addressing for the GOT.  You're thinking of how the i386 SysV ABI uses `ebx` as a GOT pointer in PIC code.

Comment: @JMcCoy: see also links to docs, tutorials, and reference manuals in [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved, thank you!

the reason my code could not detect a 64 bit value (as someone pointed out) is that doing a 32 bit operation on a register clears the upper 32 bits of that register.

```
; rax has the orginal rdi argument at this point in the code
mov rbx, rax 
xor ebx, eax ; this clears the upper 32 bits of rbx
cmp rbx, 0 ; these are equal
jne isQword ; so we don't get to isQword when we should
```